# Identifying records in MC to delete

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, contact-deletion

I'm trying to delete a large number of records from SFMC to avoid being charged extra. I've run several different SQLs to help identify the records I don't need, but when I run the Contact Count report, it still shows approx 100K billable contacts and approx 60K distinct email addresses.

Here are the SQLs I've tried:

- No Opens in past 5 days
- Leads/Contacts not in SFDC
- [Lead records in MC not in SF sync DE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301970/how-to-identify-all-records-in-mc-that-are-not-in-a-synchronized-data-extension)
- SubscriberKey as Email Address
- Leads/Contacts where SubscriberKey is Empty
- Unspecified records (DE populated by MC Support)
- [Records who have not been sent an email from XYZ journey](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300915/is-there-a-way-to-use-sql-to-identify-all-records-who-are-not-part-of-an-active/300922#300922)

These efforts reduced the count a good amount, but not as much as I was expecting.

Has anyone else gone through this process before and if so, what queries can you share that might help my case?

Comment: That's a high amount of duplicate email addresses. How many leads/contacts in total are you currently synching? A lead that is converted will remain as 2 billable contacts (1 lead, 1 contact) which could be inflating the count.

Answer (score 3):

Start with this article:

[Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

> 1) Address the cause of Contacts without channels
>   Each of the cases mentioned previously in this article are expected behavior. If you do not desire this behavior, disable the associated feature that is causing Contacts without channels.
>
> Once the feature is disabled, use the steps below to delete any Contacts without channels from your account.
>
> 2) Prepare to delete any Contacts without channels 
>   Note: You must have MobileConnect or MobilePush to complete these steps.
>
> 1. In MobileConnect or MobilePush, create a filtered mobile list that meets 4 conditions:
>
> Contact Key is not null AND Email Address is null AND Mobile Number is null AND Device ID is null ​AND Address ID is null
>
> Note: This is sourced from these attribute paths:
>
> System Data | Contact | Contact Key 
>   System Data | Email Addresses | Email Address
>   MobileConnect Data | MobileConnect Demographics | Mobile Number
>   MobilePush Data | MobilePush Demographics | Device ID
>   GroupConnect LINE Data | GroupConnect LINE Demographics | Address ID

Comment: thank you. I should have specified that we do not have access to MobileConnect and therefore are unable to create this filter without raising a case with Support. They have done this for me already, which populated all "Unspecified Contacts" as outlined in my question, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on MC Support to run this list whenever I need it. Secondly, I already ran the other query "Delete records created via Synchronized Data Sources" mentioned in the link you shared. This helped, but not enough. :-/

Comment: So it have you identified how you are adding these unwanted contacts so you don't have to keep deleting them?

Comment: Yes, they were added when the MC sync settings were updated. I've addressed the sync settings now to reflect a Sync_to_MC boolean in SFDC, but despite supposedly identifying all Leads and Contacts where SubscriberKey is Empty, the total records available for deletion is a small percentage of the total billable contact count indicated by the Contact Count Report.

Answer (score 1):

I had to go through the same hassle recently. Deleting subscribers from All Subscribers doesn't help much. You need to delete from All Contacts. What I did was this -

1. Go to Mobile Connect
2. Go to Manage Contacts >> Lists
3. Created a filtered list
4. Set it up for deletion

Hope this helps